Request for a Meta version of the informed badge
About 26% of all questions on Meta SO are closed. I'm not sure how to find the exact number of closed questions as duplicates, but looking at the new questions, it's quite a large amount. Most of the dupes closed now are duplicates of faq questions, so could we incentivize people to read the Meta FAQ index by adding a Meta version of the Informed badge? It would likely decrease the number of questions that get closed as dupes of frequently asked questions.

If Stack Overflow proper is any indication, it won't move the needle. All we'll get out if it is the ability to say, "Of course you don't know what you're doing. We can see you didn't read the ing manual."

"so could we incentivize people to read" - nope. The only information that actually reaches people is bite-sized information, provided in the moment.
